# Regex match a string whose before and after not a letter

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

for example

I would like to match three null in
`Sat:null-5:00pm`
`Sun:null-null`

but not a null in `snullagain`.

How to write such a regex in javascript?

Comment: can't you just look for `:null` ?

Comment: If you mean "English letter", you may use `(?<![a-zA-Z])null(?![a-zA-Z])`.

Comment: You could try matching the word boundary: `\bnull\b`

Comment: @icn You should clarify in your question exactly what type of `null` you want to match for

Comment: @CherryDT This will not match `1null1` or `_null_` (which might or might not be what the OP wants).

Comment: @CherryDT it is actually mostly I want!

Comment: @CherryDT onlt thing that is missing is if null is the end of a string

Comment: No that should be OK too since the end of the string counts as word boundary as well.

Comment: @icn No, it's not. You should read about what the [`\b` anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) means. And more importantly, you should include clear requirements in your question. You said _"not a letter"_, but that doesn't seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is: `\bnull\b`

That translates to "word boundary, followed by the word `null`, followed by a word boundary"

Comment: That would include the previous/next character in the match though

Comment: You're right, fixed.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this. You can achieve the same logic using just `\bnull\b` as suggested by CherryDT in the comments under the question.

Comment: I believe now after this fix you reinvented `\b` instead 

Comment: Haha yes, fair. Updated to reflect your suggestions.